# Formatting MySQL timestamp to PHP DateTime

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

How can I format a timestamp from MySQL to a date value in PHP?

Comment: *(hint)* How a date is [formatted](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) has nothing to do with how it is [represented internally](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) or how it is [stored](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html).

Comment: If mysql formatting isn't enough for you, then you can use SELECT  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecolumn) ... to get a unix timestamp for use in php's date() function. Would be a lot more optimal than parsing it with strtotime that they used in the answers below.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That's probably the way to go. You could add this to the answers if you'd like me to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formatting and storing of a date can be perfectly seperated. Use `strotime` and `strftime` to calculate timestamps and use those with `date`.

In your view:

```
date('F d, Y at g a', strtotime($storedDate));
```

Wherever you store your date

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($formattedData));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('r', strtotime($mysql_datetime_column_value));
```

See the [date()](http://php.net/date) function in the PHP documentation for more detail.